# delayed/recipies error when trying to deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy some changes to an existing ROR application using capistrano. I'm running MAC OSX and the server is Ubuntu 12.0.4. I'm new to ROR and capistrano, so here's an overview of what I've done so far. I cloned our github repo to a local folder, made my code changes, updated the github repo, installed capistrano using: `gem install capistrano`, opened terminal, changed directory into the local folder where my ROR app is located, and tried `cap deploy:check`. Note, I did not capify the project because there is an existing Deploy and Cap file in the project. When I run `cap deploy:check` I get the following output:

```
/Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- delayed/recipes (LoadError)
from /Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
from ./config/deploy.rb:2:in `load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from Capfile:4:in `load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `block in load_recipes'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/bin/cap:19:in `load'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Here is a sample of my deploy.rb file (with edits to user names, server name, etc.)

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "delayed/recipes"

set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"") # Read from local system
require 'rvm/capistrano'

set :rails_env, "production" #added for delayed job

server "myservername", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "myapp"
set :user, "deploy"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
#set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/uploads}

set :scm, "git"
set :scm_passphrase, "mypassword"
set :repository, "git@github.com:myusername/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases
after "deploy:stop",    "delayed_job:stop"
after "deploy:start",   "delayed_job:start"
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart"

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end

namespace :mailman do
  desc "Mailman::Start"
  task :start, :roles => [:app] do
    run "cd #{current_path};RAILS_ENV=#{rack_env} bundle exec script/mailman_daemon start"
  end

  desc "Mailman::Stop"
  task :stop, :roles => [:app] do
    run "cd #{current_path};RAILS_ENV=#{rack_env} bundle exec script/mailman_daemon stop"
  end

  desc "Mailman::Restart"
  task :restart, :roles => [:app] do
    mailman.stop
    mailman.start
  end
end
```

And here is a copy of the cap file:

```
load 'deploy'
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

I would really appreciate some help with this. I just need to deploy a few changes to the production environment, but I'm kind of at a stand still right now. Hopefully, I've provided enough info. However, being really new to cap and ruby, I might be overlooking something really obvious. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a pathing issue. What path is your 'delayed/recipes' a part of? Please keep in mind that require will load files from the **$LOAD_PATH** .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know our project is using delayed_jobs to manage background tasks. For some reason, I'm not seeing that in the project folder. I bet that's where the error is coming from. Thanks a ton.